# Convert Julian Date with Time to full datetime in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, julian-date

I have a field in a pandas data frame where I calculated the Julian date using to_julian_date() from a datetime64[ns] field and now have values like jul1 in the example below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':['2017-01-01 03:15:00','2017-01-01 03:15:00']})
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])

df['jul1'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['dates']).to_julian_date()
#if need remove times
df['jul2'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['dates']).floor('d').to_julian_date()
```

```
print (df)
                dates          jul1       jul2
0 2017-01-01 03:15:00  2.457755e+06  2457754.5
```

My question is: how can I convert a Julian date with time like this back into a full calendar date with time that includes the full temporal resolution possible? So if I’ve fed in a datetime down to seconds to generate the Julian equivalent, how do I reverse that Julian date back out to the full datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled across this question when trying to do the same thing myself. Turns out the solution is quite simple, but not obvious to find in the documentation. Using your example from above, I've just added the final line.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':['2017-01-01 03:15:00','2017-01-01 03:15:00']})
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])

df['jul1'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['dates']).to_julian_date()
#if need remove times
df['jul2'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['dates']).floor('d').to_julian_date()

df['dates_recovered'] = pd.to_datetime(df['jul1'], unit='D', origin='julian')
```

It think it would be helpful if there was a `from_julian_date` method to accompany the  `to_julian_date` method.

Answer (score 0):

The US Navy runs a website for Gregorian date-time <-> Julian date-time conversions:

https://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/api#jdconv

where they invite people to write API's to access the info.

Working with Julian date-times has advantages: The Julian calendar began on January 1, 4713 BC, and the conversion from Gregorian to Julian date-times is accurate to 20 microseconds on a double-precision 64 bit machine. So no Unix/Windows limitations when working with Julian date-times.

I agree: Python needs a from_julian_date method. When faced with time and date differences, I find doing the math with Julian date-times and converting back to Gregorian much, much, much easier than deciphering the confusing array of Timestamps, dt's, Datetimes, H,M,S, tz's etc...FWIW: I'm an not a professional programmer.